# If Java is pass-by-value only, can I mandate a final modifier in formal parameters?

Tags: java, pass-by-value

If Java is strictly pass-by-value for non primitive, isn't it better to establish coding standards like make all formal parameters of methods and constructors final? - to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Shahzeb Java is pass by value. Complex types are pointer types, the value of their pointers are passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If Java is strictly pass-by-value for non primitive

Java is strictly pass-by-value for ALL arguments and ALL results, **irrespective of type**.

And if you don't understand, or don't believe me, read [Java is Pass-by-Value, Dammit!](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

> ... can I mandate a final modifier in formal parameters?

Yes you could, but it would be a bad idea to do it for the reasons that you have given.

Declaring a method or constructor's formal parameters to be `final` *means something different* to the meaning that you are trying to place on it.  Specifically, it means that the parameter can't be assigned to in the body of the method / constructor.

Doing this has the following consequences:

- It will actually change the meaning of the code in a way that could cause compilation errors in some cases.  (These are good compilation errors ... because they force the programmer to stop doing something that generally makes his code less clear.  But fixing takes effort and requires retesting, etc.)
- Seasoned Java programmers are not going to read into this the meaning that you intend.  (Not that they should *need* to be reminded ...).
- Novice Java programmers are likely to be more confused ... especially if they pick up the *incorrect* notion that declaring something to be `final` alters the argument passing semantics!

So this does not achieve your aim.

The real solution is to educate people that **Java ALWAYS uses pass-by-value**.  (And that includes **beating up** people who persist in spreading false information and doubt about this ... like your question does!)

---

(In nearly all cases, it is good practice to not update formal parameters, and declaring them `final` prevents you doing this by accident.  So this is good practice.  But the reason it is good practice is not what you stated ... and if you did put this into a coding standard with the reasoning that you gave, you would *deserve to be roundly criticised*.)

And if you don't understand, or don't believe me, read [Java is Pass-by-Value, Dammit!](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

Comment: @Shahzeb No it's quite simple. Does `person = new Person("John");` change the value of the variable person outside of the function? No? Then there's no pass-by-reference (ie if you did this in c++ person would actually change outside the function). You modify the variable pointed to, which is something quite different.

Comment: @Shahzeb Oh there are quite a lot of working environments where such discussions are lead quite ferociously. I don't see how that's something bad though, it just shows that everyone is passionate about their job and programming at a whole - I'd hate to work in an environment where everyone just went "meh, who cares?". But you're right it's 5am here, no more coffee; paper almost finished -> time for bed ;)

Answer (score 4):

Shahzeb commented that Java does not pass by value for non-primitives; it is pass-by-value for non-primitives in the sense that it passes the value of a *reference* to the non-primitive.  It does not, however, copy objects when you pass them to functions.

The `final` modifier in formal parameter lists shouldn't affect callers one way or the other because methods receive copies of references and copies of primitives; they cannot affect reference and primitive values in caller code.  The `final` modifier does not prevent mutable objects from being altered through the `final` reference.  `final` can only be of any help to the code in the method it is in.

(Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is right.)

Comment: Thats my understanding too :)

Comment: Its not an easy concept to explain over blobs of text. And I'm not in the mood for drawing at the moment. (when i was teaching basic programming, I would draw little boxes and arrows to explain the concept)

Answer (score 2):

One of the use of final in parameters is to avoid your parameter value to be changed by mistake when you write a method. Consider this

```
private method1(final String name){
    ...
    ...
    String oldname = this.name;
    name = name;
}
```

You forget to add `this.name` in `name`.The compiler will give error. This help you /developer to trade a logic error into a compiler error, if you make sure the input parameter cannot be modified. Thus reduce your error prone and debug time :)

Hope it helps

Comment: `Java is pass-by-reference (pass-by-value of object references)` - except that those two things are something COMPLETELY different. If you `pass an object by reference` doing `object = new Object()` will have impact outside the function - that's not what happening in Java.

Comment: @Voo: Just take some revision again, and I have deleted the wrong part. thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover other bases, because I think this is what you are thinking about:

In C++, it is possible to declare a parameter as "const", which basically means that the data contained in this object will not change as a result of calling this function (I think).

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/CppTutorial/NOTES/PARAMS.html#constRef

Java does not have such a modifier. (In Java 7 maybe? Anyone know?)

Comment: I would argue that C++'s `const` and Java's `final` are the same. For example, C++'s `const int foo;` and Java's `final int foo;`. C++ has a more complicated syntax for const for complex types, like pointers. In Java, to apply `final` to a reference (equivalent to C++ pointer to object), you do `final Foo bar;`. In C++, to apply `const` to a pointer, you do `Foo *const bar;`. Those two have the same effect. [continued...]

Comment: C++ also allows you to apply `const` to the "thing pointed to by the pointer" using the syntax `const Foo *bar;` or `Foo const *bar;`, but the "thing pointed to by the pointer" concept does not exist in Java, so there is no equivalent. The confusion arises from the different syntax of the two languages and when people naively think that somehow `const Foo *bar;` means something like `final Foo bar;` which is not true because of the positioning of `const` in C++.

Comment: @newacct I was referring to the use of const in function parameters, but I am in no way proficient enough in C++ to comment any more so thanks for the additional information :)

Comment: it's the same in function parameters

Comment: In Java 7 and Java 8 - no.  IMO, it is unlikely that Java will ever support `const` ... even though it is a reserved word.